# Saving changes in Listview after scroll

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

In an Android app I have, there are a few `ListView`'s where the user can change row elements.  For example, in one I have a button where you can up vote user comments (think Facebook "Like" or Google+ "+1").

When the user clicks the button, the drawable image changes.  This is working good.  **The problem:**

*When the user scrolls down and then comes back up, state is not saved and it goes back to original drawable.*

Here is how I do the code in `adapter` `getView()` method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        dCBlue = (Drawable) getContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ic_comment_blue);
        dCGray = (Drawable) getContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ic_comment_gray);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.review_layout, parent,
        holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.b2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bReview2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        convertView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(null);
    }

      // later on down 

    Review r = getItem(position);
    votedOn = r.wasVoted;
    final Drawable dVBlue = (Drawable) getContext().getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_upvote_blue);
    final Drawable dVGray = (Drawable) getContext().getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_upvote_gray);

    if (votedOn.equals("1")) {
         holder.b2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, dVBlue, null);
         holder.b2.setTag(R.drawable.review_button_press);
     } else {
         holder.b2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null,dVGray, null);
         holder.b2.setTag(R.drawable.review_button);
     }

     holder.b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {

        if (holder.b2.getTag().equals(R.drawable.review_button)) {
            holder.b2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, dVBlue, null);
    holder.b2.setTag(R.drawable.review_button_press);

        } else {
    holder.b2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, dVGray, null);
        holder.b2.setTag(R.drawable.review_button);

         }
        bVote = holder.b2;
        new HelpfulTask().execute(passing);


    });
 return convertView;
```

}

Do I have this arranged out of order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see you updating your review object. You should be updating your object that represents a row to indicate the vote and then the view binding should just take care of it.

Comment: in your onclick when you update your images for the row you should be committing that information somehow to the Review object that represents the row. Then when you do getItem(position) the next time this row shows up, you will have the vote state indicated by that object